# Populate a custom attachment metadata field with data from the image's EXIF data?

Tags: uploads

I want to populate two custom fields I added from data of the image's EXIF. I added the fields by using the filter `attachment_fields_to_edit`. I can see these fields in the image details once they are uploaded. But they are empty. Can I populate these fields using data from the image's EXIF data automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the `add_attachment` and `edit_attachment` action hooks and use PHP's `exif_read_data()` to add the EXIF data to your attachment's metadata:

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse302908_add_exif' );
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse302908_add_exif' );

/**
 * Inserts metadata from an image's EXIF data.
 *
 * @param  int $post_id The attachment's post ID.
 * @return void
 */
function wpse302908_add_exif( $post_id ) {
    // These are the keys for the data you want from the EXIF data.
    $exif_keys = array( 'key_1', 'key_2' );
    $exif_data = exif_read_data( get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id );
    foreach ( $exif_keys as $exif_key ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $exif_key, $exif_data[ $exif_key ] );
    }

}
```

### Notes

- This code is *untested*.
- I assumed that your desired meta key names match the ones provided in the image's EXIF data.
- This code doesn't check to make sure you're uploading an image; you'll probably want to insert some checks for that.

### References

- [`add_attachment` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_attachment/)
- [`edit_attachment` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_attachment/)
- [`exif_read_data()`](https://php.net/exif_read_data)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/)
- [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Comment: `update_post_meta( $post_id, $exif_key, $exif_data[ $exif_key ] );` This line looks like its updating the EXIF fields of WordPress. Am I right?

Comment: It's meant to add or update the metadata for the attachment (which is a type of post) with the values pulled from the image EXIF data.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but its not working.

Comment: What keys are you trying to get from the EXIF data? What are the metadata key names that you've selected?

Comment: `Exif.Image.ImageDescription` and `Exif.Photo.UserComment`. I am setting these values in a Python script I made. I can retrieve the values in Python just fine. I'm just using them to hold custom values. And I have made custom metadata fields for them in WordPress.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Are those fields in the photo's EXIF data when it's uploaded to WordPress (either natively or because you've added them)?

Comment: I have added them. But I think WordPress extracts only certain amount of data from the entire metadata.